# Arrayformula with sum and offset condition

Tags: conditional-statements, sum, array-formulas, offset

I have monthwise data in column S3:Z3035, month named in column S,T... etc as April, may... So on.

Client name is in column A. I put month in dropdwon in cell B2. I want sum of individual client in column AA with condition of month i.e. if I select B=June then client wise sum of April to June should come in column AA, if I select B=November then client wise sum of April to November should come in column AA.

I used offset with sum and it is working. I want a single formula with array

I want a single formula with array